# Fire Django Signal's from the command line

Tags: python, django, signals

As the title says im am trying to fire a django signal from the command line, rather then from in the view/model, but i cant figure out exactly how to do this, or how to access much of django's workings from the command line, i assume you need to be in "manage.py shell" or at least pythons shell, but i cant find any documentation to help me get any further.

Does anyone know if this is possible to begin with and if so how one goes about doing it.

Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need signals. See [custom manager command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Just write your custom command which will do the necessary action (from documentation):

```
# file <app folder>/management/commands/closepoll.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from example.polls.models import Poll

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '<poll_id poll_id ...>'
    help = 'Closes the specified poll for voting'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for poll_id in args:
            try:
                poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=int(poll_id))
            except Poll.DoesNotExist:
                raise CommandError('Poll "%s" does not exist' % poll_id)

            poll.opened = False
            poll.save()

            self.stdout.write('Successfully closed poll "%s"\n' % poll_id)
```

The new custom command can be called using `python manage.py closepoll <poll_id>`.

Also, if you still want to do it through the signals, just send a signal from the method `Command.handle`:

```
mysignal = django.dispatch.Signal(providing_args=["foo", "bar"])

...

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '<foo> <bar>'

    def handle(self, foo, bar):

        mysignal.send(sender=self, foo=foo, bar=bar)
```

Comment: Thanks, the signal is the integral partto what im trying to perform which you answered that it is possible to mix that into the manager commands so thankyou